Ideally shouldnt this code free tmp before ending?
Im confused on why is this code freeing list but not tmp after setting list to point to where tmp points (list = tmp;)
// Implements a list of numbers with an array of dynamic size

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    // List of size 3
    int *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize list of size 3 with numbers
    *list = 1;
    *(list + 1) = 2;
    *(list + 2) = 3;

    // List of size 4
    int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        free(list);
        return 1;
    }

    // Copy list of size 3 into list of size 4
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = list[i];
    }

    // Add number to list of size 4
    tmp[3] = 4;

    // Free list of size 3
    free(list);

    // Remember list of size 4
    list = tmp;

    // Print list
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list[i]);
    }

    // Free list
    free(list);
    return 0;
}



Both list and tmp are variables. You do not free variables, you free memory. Both allocated chunks of memory are free'd by the two free calls.

Suppose the first malloc returns 0x1234 and assigns it to list, and the 2nd malloc returns 0x5678 and assigns it to tmp.  The first free frees 0x1234, and the 2nd free frees 0x5678.  The name of the variable used to pass the value to free is irrelevant.

Why do you think it's not freeing tmp?

The second free(list) is equivalent to free(tmp), since both variables contain the same value.

How do you determine whether allocated memory was freed or not?

The second call to free(list) could be replaced with a call free(tmp) with no change in meaning, since at the second call list == tmp.

run valgrind  and see the report generated, a handy tool

Side note: dont write *(foo + bar), write foo[bar] instead.

@ticktalk It won't display anything of value in this case though, since there are no memory leaks or corruptions, the program is working as intended.

The only thing that matters is that you call free with the same address as you once got handed by malloc. The memory allocated is associated with that address, not with a pointer variable name.

At the first free(list); you free the first chunk allocated with  int *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));.
list = tmp; Now both list and tmp point at the same location, the address returned from this malloc call: int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
From there we could either do free(list) or free(tmp), it doesn't matter since they point at the same location and it's the original address returned from the malloc(4 ... call.
After the second free() both list and tmp are "dangling pointers", they point at a memory region which is no longer available. Therefore it is often good practice to set the pointer(s) to NULL directly after calling free.

